# Cannot find directory /etc/config.sys/ on linux mint

Tags: opensuse, linux-mint

What is an alternative to OPENSUSE /etc/config.sys/ on LINUX MINT or UBUNTU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `/etc/sysconfig`?  Because according to [the documentation](http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch13s06.html), /etc/sysconfig is sort of a catch-all system configuration location that's unique to SuSE.  Kind of like how `/etc/rc.conf` is (sort of) unique to Arch.  Ubuntu's system configuration is spread across [many files and directories](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=946682) in `/etc`.  Really though, if there is something that you want to tweak that you're unsure about, I guarantee you're not the first person to do it--community documentation is your friend.

Comment: Namely, I wanted to add a new Apache module in /etc/config.sys/apache2
file. The tutorial I took, has all the stuff written for OpenSuSE. I will refer to documentation, thanks